# Getting image from gallery of Facebook and show it in iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, uiimageview

I want get image from public perfil of Facebook and show it in my iPhone. I'm using the Facebook Developer method "getPhoto" but I can´t show any image?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",objectID];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

As told Previously your problem to retrieve the object id. Here is the solution:-
To retrieve the images of your friend. Create the connection with the url

```
 NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=%@",accessTokenValue];
```

above url when hit returns an array of dictionary in which name of your friend and his id is written. Just Json parse that you will get the id of the person.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use graph api for this purpose

```
 NSString *url = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"https://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture",objectID];
 UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
```

Comment: Thanks friend, but my problem is that i can´t get the objectID to can show all image of public album of facebook.

Comment: you can use **me** instead of objectID.